# How to save and call Highscore in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to save my games highscore in cocos2d, i already have a variable called score which displays the score while playing the game and i would like the variable for highscore to be "highscore", how do i code this into my game? UPDATE i have attempted to add it in but still no luck, here is the code in my init

```
UserHighScoreLabel = [[defaults valueForKey:@"highscore"] integerValue];

    UserHighScoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14];
    UserHighScoreLabel.position = ccp(65, 200);
    UserHighScoreLabel.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
    [self addChild:UserHighScoreLabel];

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:Strategyscore forKey:@"highscore"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: You can use UserDefaults

Comment: How would i code this?

Comment: I would recommend doing that with xCode, or AppCode or even vi. There are loads of questions (and answers) on the same topic around here ... go look.

Comment: how to draw line and make sprite to follow that line and erase that line?

Comment: i have answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSUserDefaults to save the high score on the device so it can retrieved at any time.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//saving
[defaults setValue:yourHighScore forKey:@"SavedHighScore"];
[defaults synchronize]; //you must synchronize to save


//retreiving
int highScore;
highScore = [[defaults valueForKey:@"SavedHighScore"] intValue];

//set label text to retrieved high score
UserHighScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore];
```

You could also store a JSON or XML string as the user default and parse it once you retreive it.

If you have a HighScore object or you are storing a lot of values, `CoreData` may be worth using, but it is not optimal if you are simply storing a few high scores.

EDIT with your code

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

highScore = [[defaults valueForKey:@"SavedHighScore"] intValue];

//init before setting the text
UserHighScoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14];

//set label text to retrieved high score
UserHighScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore];

UserHighScoreLabel.position = ccp(65, 200);
UserHighScoreLabel.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
[self addChild:UserHighScoreLabel];
```

Comment: Do i save and load this in my init? or somewhere else? i haven't had any experience with neuserdefaults

Comment: You can load this whenever you need to access your high score, whether that be on the app's load or sometime after. You can save at anytime as well.

Comment: What you are doing is saving the high score and doing nothing with it. Do you mean to be loading the current high score and displaying it in the label?

Comment: Yeah I want to load it in the label, how would I do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I added a line to my answer on how to set the labels text correctly

Comment: I haven't been successful with adding this to my game, my game now runs at 30fps I have removed the code but i am still experiencing the lag any ideas?

Comment: Accessing NSUserDefaults would not cause any lag-- something else is causing that. As for it not working, you will need to actually save a high score before anything will show up. You will need to put the saving code (setValueForSet) wherever you want the high score to save. (ie after you die or whatever)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly fetch your last high score.

```
int highScore = [[defaults valueForKey:@"highscrore"] integerValue];
```

Now compare it with last high score if it's higher than old store then new highscore.

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:score forKey:@"highscrore"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: how to draw line and make sprite to follow that line and erase that line?